# Updating a localStorage item using a checkbox

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Basically, I want to toggle a checkbox being switched on or off, and save this setting as either a 1 or 0 respectively in a localStorage item. The setting needs to be stored for the user.

Considering I have a checkbox input with an id of 'x', this script works perfectly:

```
$("#x").click(function () {
    if (checkboxstore == false) {
        alert("Tickbox has been turned on");
        localStorage.setItem("checkboxstore", 1);
    } else if (checkboxstore == true) {
        alert("Tickbox has been turned off");
        localStorage.setItem("checkboxstore", 0);
    };
});
```

Sadly though, it only works once. The page loads, the input is 'off', I click the input, and I get the alert

> "Tickbox has been turned on"

and the localStorage item "Tickbox" is set to 1. Brilliant. It works the otherway to, when the page loads and the input is 'on'.

But then, that's it. No matter how much I toggle the input, despite the tick changing, the localStorage item is not updated! I constantly get the same message, ""Tickbox has been turned on" regardless of whether I'm turning the tick on or off.

It only works on initial load or on resetting the localStorage value.

Why is this? How can I get it to work over and over again without the refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need two things:

(1) A function that will alter the state of your checkbox based on the value in localStorage when the documents loads. Something like the following (untested) code should do:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  if( localStorage.getItem( 'checkboxstore' ) ) {
    $('#x').prop( 'checked', 'checked' );
  } else {
    $('#x').removeProp( 'checked' );
  }
} );
```

(2) You'll need to replace `checkboxstore` with `localStorage.getItem('checkboxstore')`. It now checks a non-existing variable.

```
$("#x").click(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('checkboxstore') == false) {
        alert("Tickbox has been turned on");
        localStorage.setItem("checkboxstore", 1);
    } else {
        alert("Tickbox has been turned off");
        localStorage.setItem("checkboxstore", 0);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a plunker and you can play with it if you want.
http://plnkr.co/edit/iYLFc8V1PzZ5tBJu16g5?p=preview

```
$("#x").change(function(e) {
        if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
        console.log("true");
    } else if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
        console.log("false");
    }
  });
```